# Aligning div icons to the center with the parent div to the top-right

Tags: html, css

Hello stackoverflowers,

I am aiming for the following layout: https://www.screencast.com/t/wZeMOhzE7K

My current layout has the top-right div squishing into the div icons that should be centered.

Here is the CSS/HTML. Help would be much appreciated.

```css
.places {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.places article {
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*exercise 8*/
.price_by_night {
    color: #FF5A5F;
    border: 4px solid #FF5A5F;
    border-radius: 50%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.information {
  height: 80px;
  border-top: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
}

.max_guest {
  background-image:url("images/icon_group.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
}

.number_rooms {
  background-image:url("images/icon_bed.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
}

.number_bathrooms {
  background-image:url("images/icon_bath.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="8-places.css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
      <section class="places">
        <h1>Places</h1>
        <article class="home">
        <h2>Home</h2>
          <div class="price_by_night">$80</div>
          <div class="information">
            <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
            <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
            <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
            <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> John Lennon</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="apartment">
        <h2>Apartment</h2>
          <div class="price_by_night">$65</div>
          <div class="information">
            <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
            <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
            <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
            <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Tina Fey</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="dorm">
        <h2>Dorm</h2>
          <div class="price_by_night">$20</div>
          <div class="information">
            <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
            <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
            <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
            <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Lorie</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take a look at it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289681/aligning-div-icons-to-the-center-with-the-parent-div-to-the-top-right/42289873#42289873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this will help you. 
You have to add the background-image size and position to acheive its position and size related property.

```css
.places {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.places article {
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*exercise 8*/

.price_by_night {
  color: #FF5A5F;
  border: 4px solid #FF5A5F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.information {
  height: 80px;
  border-top: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
}

.max_guest {
  background-image: url("http://workshops.jazzbooks.com/wp/wp-content/themes/mydreamdesign/images/icon-author.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_rooms {
  background-image: url("http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/bedroom-icon-0.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_bathrooms {
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/architecture-interior/24/architecture-interior-17-512.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="8-places.css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <section class="places">
    <h1>Places</h1>
    <article class="home">
      <div class="price_by_night">$80</div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> John Lennon</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="apartment">
      <div class="price_by_night">$65</div>
      <h2>Apartment</h2>
      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Tina Fey</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="dorm">
      <div class="price_by_night">$20</div>
      <h2>Dorm</h2>

      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Lorie</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey vijay, almost there, the same issue with everyone else, the div icons are not quite centered. :(

Comment: your answer is the best, though the only critique is we have to re-order the <div class="price_by_night">$80</div> which doesn't make sense logically, but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope is this you want

```css
.places {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.places article {
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*exercise 8*/
.price_by_night {
    color: #FF5A5F;
    border: 4px solid #FF5A5F;
    border-radius: 50%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}

.information {
  height: 80px;
  border-top: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
}

.max_guest {
  background-image:url("https://s32.postimg.org/n1npuo6h1/test.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position:center top;
}

.number_rooms {
  background-image:url("https://s32.postimg.org/n1npuo6h1/test.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position:center top;
}

.number_bathrooms {
  background-image:url("https://s32.postimg.org/n1npuo6h1/test.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position:center top;
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="places">
        <h1>Places</h1>
        <article class="home">
        <h2>Home</h2>
          <div class="price_by_night">$80</div>
          <div class="information">
            <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
            <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
            <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
            <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> John Lennon</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="apartment">
        <h2>Apartment</h2>
          <div class="price_by_night">$65</div>
          <div class="information">
            <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
            <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
            <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
            <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Tina Fey</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="dorm">
        <h2>Dorm</h2>
          <div class="price_by_night">$20</div>
          <div class="information">
            <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
            <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
            <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
            <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Lorie</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>
```

Comment: This works, but also runs into the same issue of not centering the div icons. Almost @vedankita!

Comment: yours was the second best answer, but when I input it with my code, it made my popover menus transparent [not added in the code I put on this page]

Answer (score 0):

Place the  `<div class="price_by_night">$80</div>` line before `<h2>Home</h2>`

And it works....

See a working codepen : http://codepen.io/shubham93/pen/PWggev

Comment: You're right shubham, that does work a bit. The div icon elements still don't center unfortunately.

Comment: which one ? @jimmytt

Comment: all three of the div icons still don't center with your codepen @shubham :(

Comment: @jimmytt check again i've demonstrated with one icon.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.places article {
  position: relative;
}
.price_by_night {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @arthurmoroz - this works without moving around the 'price_by_night' div - but also runs into the same issue of the div icon elements not centering.

Comment: .information {text-align: center;} ? If you mean about icon background position use .max_guest {background-position: 50% 50%;}

Comment: just tried .max_guest {background-position: 50% 50%;} - doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: can you send me screen with description and icon images

Comment: adding `.information {text-align: center}` + `.max_guest {background-position: 50% 50%;}` + `.number_rooms {background-position: 50% 50%;}` + `.number_bathrooms {background-position: 50% 50%;}` makes it worse: https://www.screencast.com/t/WQrZNDLsMGP

Comment: This is the best looking one yet, only thing is "Owner: John Lennon" is now centered, when it should be aligned left.

Comment: And icons are off center (in addition "Owner: John lennon" being centered): https://www.screencast.com/t/06Dq2tKzeXC5

Comment: for icons add `background-position: 50% 0`